# Why cant I download data of multiple stocks from yahoo finance

Tags: r, finance, quantitative

Hi I am trying to download data of multiple stocks from yahoo finance using the quantmod package in R. My method is to create a function using the getSymbols function, and use lapply to apply this to a vector of ticker symbols. Below is my code

```
get_data <- function(x){getSymbols(x, 
                                   from = "2017-01-01",
                                   to = "2021-03-15",
                                   auto.assign = FALSE)}

tickers <- c("AAPL","GOOG","FB","TSLA")

mydata <- lapply(tickers,get_data)
```

running the last step does not give me the data, just a list with all the tickers stored as characters.
Would appreciate if anyone could tell me where my code is going wrong. Cheers

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: It works also for me, what is your output of `mydata` ?

Comment: what kind of output do you get? my output is a list with the ticker symbols stored as character values, instead of xts objects which i would expect to get..

Comment: `mydata`
[[1]]
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2017-01-03   28.9500   29.0825  28.6900    29.0375   115127600      27.45994
2017-01-04   28.9625   29.1275  28.9375    29.0050    84472400      27.42920
2017-01-05   28.9800   29.2150  28.9525    29.1525    88774400      27.56869

Comment: Can you update with your output of `mydata` ?

Comment: This is weird..your output is what i would expect to get. Thanks anyways. I will try again after restarting

Comment: So this is my output. > data[[1]]
[1] "AAPL"

Comment: Maybe you can try update quantmod package but this looks very strange and i really don't know where it could come from